# Epic/Legendary participation Badge - Counter

Tags: support, badges

I'm wondering if is there a way to discover how many times I've earned the *200 daily reputation*.
Is it shown somewhere in the personal badges page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the reputation calculation page

```
stackoverflow.com/reputation
```

At the bottom you see something like this

> earned at least 200 reputation on **x** days

Comment: thanks, i missed this page! Is it explained somewhere in the faq?

Comment: **Note:** This number is not 100% accurate because there are other factors that might cause a day to count or not count. It's about the most accurate number you can find, though.